# Georeferencing with only single coordinate

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I'm currently examining the new proposed sampling points based on a drainage map without coordinates. Previously, I was only given a single coordinate given by the consultants for their monitoring works. I wonder whether I can use their given coordinate to do georeferencing for this map.

Comment: You have a tag for QGIS but do not mention in your question body whether that is the GIS software that you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Only if you have also a scale and orientation then a single coordinate will be sufficient, otherwise two coordinates is a bare minimum.